# Gvim paste using Control+Shift+V, while leaving Visual Block Mode Control+V

Tags: vim, gvim, vimrc, gvimrc

Is there a way to map paste to control+shift+v, and leave visual block mode as control+v in gvim?

I use both quite often.

Comment: Just use the built-in `"+p` or [`i Ctrl-R +`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22433635/405550).

Answer (score 4):

This is not an authoritative answer, but there doesn't appear to be any way to distinguish between Ctrl+Shift+<letter> and Ctrl+<letter> in gvim.

I tested this using gvim 7.3.138 for Windows and gvim 7.3.189 for X on Linux. I entered insert mode, typed Ctrl-V to insert the next key literally (see ":help i_CTRL-V"), then typed Ctrl-V. The result appeared as `^V`. I repeated the experiment, typing Ctrl-Shift-V at the end. The result again appeared as `^V`.

There is also a to-do item (":help todo.txt") that suggests that handling the two cases separately is not implemented but is being considered.

> 8   Should mapping <C-A> and <C-S-A> both work?

Answer (score 2):

`<C-v>` already does what you want.

For the other one it's going to be more complicated: Some (most?) terminals treat `<CONTROL><SHIFT>` exactly like `<CONTROL>`. So `<CONTROL><SHIFT>v` will *probably* work in GVim but the the mapping will be useless in regular `vim`.

Also, which "paste" do you want to map: `p` or `P` or `"_dP` or another one?

Answer (score 0):

In gvim 9.1, I can map both `<C-V>` & `<C-S-V>` on Windows and Linux(v9.1.0139). Just check with

```
nmap <C-V> :echo "C-V"<CR>
nmap <C-S-V> :echo "C-S-V"<CR>
```

**Note:** If `<C-S-V>` is mapped, I have to remap `<C-V>` as `noremap <C-V> <C-V>` to preserve the visual-block selection function of `<C-V>`.

Comment: Actually, vim 8.1 can distinguishes between <C-S-V> and <C-V> mappings (https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/23344/20313).